# Unity: visual scripting package import error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have erorrs while unity loading.I use unity 2021.3.5f1 Personal. Now i just removed visual scripting package, but its compromise. I tried unistall and install unity, removed floder of package, its in all projects

List of errors:

```
>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/SceneVariables.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/State@32x.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/StateMachine@32x.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/UnityMessageListener@32x.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/VariablesAsset@32.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/VariablesSaver@32x.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/SettingsProvider has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Dependencies/ReorderableList/Internal/SerializedPropertyUtility.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Documentation/XmlDocumentationTags.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Inspection/Primitives/UintInspector.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Inspection/Primitives/UlongInspector.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Inspection/Primitives/UshortInspector.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Inspection/Unity has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Interface/Colors/SkinnedColor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Serialization has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/SerializedProperties has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/System.Threading.defines has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Threading has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Unity.VisualScripting.Core.Editor.asmdef has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Utilities has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Utilities/WarningLevel.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Variables has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Widgets has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Windows has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Windows/Sidebars has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Windows/SinglePageWindow.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Windows/TabbedPage.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Windows/UpdateWizard has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Windows/WebView.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Windows/WebWindow.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Windows/WindowClose.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Windows/Wizard.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Windows/WrappedEditorWindow.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/YamlDotNet.defines has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Flow has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Nesting/SuperUnitDescriptor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Nesting/SuperUnitEditor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Nesting/SuperUnitWidget.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Nesting/UnitPortDefinitionUtility.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Flow/Units/UnitEditor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Flow/Units/UnitInspector.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Flow/Units/UnitWidget.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Shared has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Shared/Unity.VisualScripting.Shared.Editor.asmdef has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/Description/StateMachineDescriptor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/Description/StateMacroDescriptor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/States/StateAnalysis.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/States/StateDescription.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/States/StateDescriptor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/States/StateEditor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/States/StateTransitionAnalysis.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/States/StateWidget.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/States/SuperStateDescriptor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/States/SuperStateEditor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/States/SuperStateWidget.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/Transitions/StateTransitionEditor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/Transitions/StateTransitionWidget.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.State/Transitions/TriggerStateTransitionWidget.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Graphics/SetupSelector.afphoto has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Graphics/Structure_16x.ai has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Graphics/Variables.afphoto has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/MonoBehaviourMessageListeners/UnityOnTriggerEnterMessageListener.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/MonoBehaviourMessageListeners/UnityOnTriggerExit2DMListener.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/MonoBehaviourMessageListeners/UnityOnTriggerStay2DMListener.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/MonoBehaviourMessageListeners/UnityOnTriggerStayMListener.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/UIEventsInterfacesListeners has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/UIEventsInterfacesListeners/UnityOnPointerExitMessageListener.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/UIEventsInterfacesListeners/UnityOnScrollMessageListener.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/UIEventsInterfacesListeners/UnityOnSelectMessageListener.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/UIEventsInterfacesListeners/UnityOnSubmitMessageListener.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/UIEventsListeners has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Reflection/Operators/UnaryOperatorHandler.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Reflection/Optimization/StaticPropertyAccessor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/SerializedProperties/SerializedPropertyProvider.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/SerializedProperties/SerializedPropertyProviderAttribute.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Variables/VariablesAsset.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Variables/VariablesSaver.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/SelectOnInteger.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/SelectOnString.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/SelectUnit.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/SelectUnit_T.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/Sequence.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/SwitchOnEnum.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/SwitchOnInteger.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/SwitchOnString.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/SwitchUnit.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/Throw.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/ToggleFlow.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/ToggleValue.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/TryCatch.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Control/While.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector2/Vector2Normalize.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector2/Vector2PerSecond.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector2/Vector2Project.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector2/Vector2Round.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector2/Vector2Subtract.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector2/Vector2Sum.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector3/Vector3MoveTowards.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector3/Vector3Multiply.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector3/Vector3Normalize.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector3/Vector3PerSecond.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector3/Vector3Project.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector3/Vector3Round.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector3/Vector3Subtract.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector3/Vector3Sum.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector4/Vector4Subtract.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Math/Vector4/Vector4Sum.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Framework/Variables/Obsolete/VariableUnit.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.Flow/Ports/ValuePortDefinition.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Runtime/VisualScripting.State has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/SceneVariables.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/State@32x.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/StateMachine@32x.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/UnityMessageListener@32x.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/VariablesAsset@32.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>The .meta file Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/IconMap/VariablesSaver@32x.png.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete
>The .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/SettingsProvider has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Dependencies/ReorderableList/Internal/SerializedPropertyUtility.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Documentation/XmlDocumentationTags.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Inspection/Primitives/UintInspector.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Inspection/Primitives/UlongInspector.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Inspection/Primitives/UshortInspector.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Inspection/Unity has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Interface/Colors/SkinnedColor.cs has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/Serialization has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

>Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/Editor/VisualScripting.Core/SerializedProperties has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.
```

Comment: Ok. So let’s boil this down. You had a project. Removes the visual scripting package. Had you used it to make code? And now you get a bucket load of whines about your meta files. 

Well. Id close unity. revert to last known good in our source control. Delete the library and temp folders inside your project area. See if it now opens correctly.

Comment: Adding to Mr Bugs, fine comment, remember the **Library** folder is essentially just a Unity internal _cache_ of your project (particularly graphical).  [You don't add it to version control and is perfectly safe to delete](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html).  Unity will re-create it when you next open the project.  For this reason it is a great way to reset/clean-up Unity if things go wrong without fear of losing important work.

Comment: These errors not just in this project, if i create new project then i'l too have these errors, but this new project is empty. I tried delete library folder. It didnt help

Comment: I dont use vcs in these projects